# Finding solutions if existed in this number theory - prime numbers problem.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was working on a problem involving prime number and I reached a point where I could not solve an equation, and the equation is.
Given that $a,b$ and $c$ are positive integers which satisfies that both $a$ and $b $ are less than $c$.
And satisfy the following equation
$$ac=b^2 +1$$
Find solutions if theres any, if there exists infintly many solutions find $a$ and $ab$ as functions in tearms of $c$.

(The original problem was if given a number $s$, find the biggest prime divisor for ($s^2 +1$). And after some conclusions I came up with the above equation and didnt know how to find a solution, so if the first problem cannot be answered I hope that the second one can be).

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange. The questions you ask are more or less about factoring S^2+1. This is an extremely difficult question. For instance when I was young, I was told it is unknown whether there exists infinitely many values of S such that S^2+1 is prime. I think the question is still open today.

Comment: $AC = B^2+1$ has solutions whenever $B^2+1$ is composite.  Examples are $B^2+1=10,26,50,65,82,122$ etc.  As for $A,B$ in terms of $C$ than $B=\sqrt{AC-1}$ and $A = \frac {B^2+1}C$.  I don't see why you'd assume that infinite number of solutions would mean solutions for *every* $C$.....

Comment: @arnaud.  This is the exact opposite.  We are looking for examples where $S^2 + 1$ is composite and it is easy to know there are infinitely many of *those*.

Comment: Thank you both for answering but let me tell you more about this problem, intially S had specific valuse S=111 and 421 and the question was was find the biggest prime divisor for 111^2 +1 and 421^2 +1 so i though why not generalize the idea and i did so, so the question became how can we relate between the prime divisors of $S^2+1$ and S it self, i changed P the prime divisor of $S^2+1$ to C and i made it into a number theory problem in hope of finding a relation between S and P (remember P is the prime divisor of $S^2+1$ ), in the end can we find such relation and how so?

Comment: And if we can find a relation between P and S ,can we express P in terms of S or the other way around?

Comment: @Ak2399 are you fixing the value of $c$?

Comment: Ah: you want S^2+1 to be congruent to 0 mod P. This means S is a root of minus one. This problem is well-known.

Comment: @Arnaud C is the prime divisors of $s^2+1$ so no it is not fixed and have many values

Comment: @Arnaud can you direct me somewhere for more information about this well known problem

Comment: Yes, I can. It is the theory of quadratic residues and of the Legendre symbol. It will only be useful if you fix P, though, and try to find all possible S such that P divides S^2+1.

Comment: thank you I appreciate your help.

Comment: Let me add one more comment: for a given P prime, (there exists S such that S^2 = -1 mod P) if and only if ( P = 1 mod 4). Then there are infinitely many positive values of S. Not sure it helps with your initial question which I still do not really understand.

Comment: @Arnaud intersting fact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your letters to become $$ y^2 - z x = -1. $$
The automorphisms (with positive determinant) of the quadratic form $y^2 - zx$ are known, and parametrized by the modular group. So, given $ps-qr = 1,$ so
$$
\det
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & q \\
r & s \\
\end{array}
\right) = 1
$$ 
we construct
$$
W =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p^2 & 2pq & q^2 \\
pr & ps+qr& qs \\
r^2 & 2rs & s^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The Hessian matrix of the quadratic form is
$$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and we have arranged $$  W^T H W = H.  $$
This means that, if
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y  \\
z \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
solves $y^2 - zx = -1,$ so does every
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p^2 x + 2pq y + q^2 z \\
pr x + (ps+qr) y + qs z \\
r^2 x +2rs y + s^2 z \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
For example, if we take $x=1, y=0, z=1$ to begin, 
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p^2  + q^2  \\
pr  + qs  \\
r^2  + s^2  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is a solution vector whenever $ps-qr = 1$